# irc server response to JOIN comment

Tags: python, join, network-programming, irc, hexchat

I'm new with writing an IRC sever.
I get Log from joining the channel in freenode connection .
The server response to :
/JOIN #h 
was
:test!~test@151.232.114.48 JOIN #h * :realname

and test was my nickname.

Does anyone know that , what is exactly 151.232.114.48 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of JOIN would be who is doing the joining, if the nick of that is your nick then that would be your hostname.